# Microsoft Graph API: "responseRequested" Attribute in "Update Event" does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As written in [Microsoft Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update), Event update endpoint allows `responseRequested` as one of the input property. It says:

> Set to true if the sender would like a response when the event is
>   accepted or declined.

I tried setting it to `false` and I'm expecting it to have similar behavior with "Request responses" button in the UI. Unfortunately, it does not work as I'm expecting it to behave.

For example, in the web UI, if you turn "Request responses" off, no notification will be sent to the attendees and a message that shows no attendance response is required.

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOkiO.png)

[UI Screenshot - Expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUaVs.png)

For the code itself:

```
type UpdateEventRequest struct {
    ResponseRequested bool `json:"responseRequested,omitempty"`
    End *DateTimeTimeZone `json:"end,omitempty"`
}

type DateTimeTimeZone struct {
    DateTime string `json:"dateTime,omitempty"`
    TimeZone string `json:"timeZone,omitempty"`
}

func NewDateTimeTimeZone(t time.Time) *DateTimeTimeZone {
    return &DateTimeTimeZone{
        DateTime: t.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999"),
        TimeZone: t.Location().String(),
    }
}
```

When I tried to update an event to the following:

```
&UpdateEventRequest{
    ResponseRequested: false,
    End:               NewDateTimeTimeZone(newEventEndTime),
}
```

Event end time is updated properly to `newEventEndTime`. However, `ResponseRequested` doesn't seem to update anything.

Am I missing something here? My initial goal is to change event end time via API without requiring attendance to submit "Yes/No" response. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Statements like "it does not work as I'm expecting it to behave" tells us neither how it is behaving _or_ how you expect it to behave. :) Also, please include the code you're using to call the API. If the issue is with how you're calling it, it would be impossible to uncover that from your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Sorry for the unclear questions. I am adding several parts (what I'm expecting it to behave and some sample code with actions) on the original question. If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks!